# MSBuild: How to keep additional file when using project dependency?

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have 2 C# project, A and B.
In csproj file of A, it will copy a file C to the target folder using Copy Task

Then project B refers project A using `<ProjectReference>` in B's csproj file.

Now the problem is, when building project B, it will not have C in target folder, any idea?

Comment: Is there a reason why you  arecopying File_C with a Copy task in Project_A, instead of adding it as a Content or None item in the project and setting CopyToOutputDirectory Always/PreserveNewest?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `Copy` Task in project A, could you add the file to be copied as a content item with the `CopyToOutputDirectory` tag set as `Always` like so:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="SomeFile.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

(This can also be done in Visual Studio's GUI by setting the "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always" in the files properties)

This should then behave as you desire when Project A is referenced by Project B the file C (SomeFile.txt) will appear both in Project B and Project A's output directory.

I've tested this on Visual Studio 2013 and this works as expected. Be aware though of the limitations of CopyToOutputDirectory it will attempt to recreate the folder structure in which it was stored in the output directory which is not always desirable.